# Dynamic generation of HTML based on an object type

Tags: jsf-2

I'm new to JSF so sorry if my question is trivial.

I have to present a list of items of three different types: let's say books, software and courses with different metadata (attributes) and requiring different visual representation.

Each of these items inherits from an abstract Item class, so I've a list of Items.

I thought to declare an abstract method `getHtml()` in the Item class so that each subclass can implement it's own "renderer" . Then in the XHTML page I'll call the `getHtml()` method using EL.
The question is: is this the correct way?
I see some drawbacks:

1. model mixed with view
2. HTML generated by means of Java code (quite difficult to maintain).

Any suggestion is appreciated.

I don't know if this synthetic presentation is clear enough: in case, please ask for clarifications.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks a lot, BalusC! You have driven me on the right rail. I knew what I need, but I didn't know what to ask. The annswers you pointed out are what I was looking for. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a page for choosing between the three, say, a drop dow list.
2. For the view,  create three files: book.xhtml, boftware.xhtml, and courses.xhtml.
3. Then create one managed bean.

   ```
   @ManagedBean
   public class BkSoCoSelector {
   private String myChoice = null;
   //add setter and getter. 
   //add no-arg constructor. 
   }
   ```
4. Create a method in the above class to make dynamic choice[see example].note: The choice below is based on #1 above, the drop down list.

   `public String pageSelector(){
       //if null, return nothing.
       //if this.myChoice == book, return book; //no file extension needed.
       //do the same for the other files.
   }`
5. On main page, #1, add the following

   `<h:commandButton value = "Submit" action = "#{bkSoCoSelector.pageSelector()}"/>`

To Summarise:

- Give the user a choice
- Set the chosen value to the instance variable.
  //done behind the scene.
- Get the now set instance variable.
- Base on the value of the instance variables, select a a page to display.

Comment: Xenwar, thanks for the quick answer. I can not apply it to my problem because the choice of the item type is not feasable. The list is a result set originating from Elasticsearch, and so I need to present all the items together. The BalusC comment indicated the correct way to dinamically load a XHTML fragment that can present all the required information in a list of results. However, thanks again for your proposal.